# How to move image down using vba in powerpoint from excel?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to vba and macros in powerpoint.. What is the correct syntax to position an image down -30?

```
PPT.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 9

Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
' Reference active presentation
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
' Reference active slide
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides _
    (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
' Copy chart as a picture
ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, _
    Format:=xlPicture
' Paste chart
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
' Align pasted chart

Dim xyz As Shape
Set xyz = PPSlide.Shapes.Selection


PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
xyz.Top = xyz.Top - 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Based on your code sample, I think you want to try something like this:

```
 PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
' Align pasted chart

PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top = PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top + 30
```

You can take out the lines referring to xyz.

Comment: I tried to implement something like that, but it doesn't work.. see my updated code above.

Comment: What is not working? What error are you getting?  To move the image down lower in the page, you definitely need to ADD 30 to Top, not subtract as your code shows.

Comment: ty so much I've been stuck on this for a couple days! While I can get by with excel and VBA for the most part, programming for Word or PowerPoint is a struggle for me. Do you have any good online references for working with those? I can't seem to find any.. thanks again for your help!!